# sql return the id of the row that is causing the error "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint"

Tags: sql, constraints

Having the following query:

```
begin try
    delete from myTable where id < @id
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;   
END CATCH;
```

When this query throws the error mention in the title (The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint), is there a way to get the row that made the delete query to fail and put it in a message?

The thing is that this query fails random (1-2 times per month) and I am not able to find why, eve if I check it's constrains, it's FK's with the other tables...

I am using sql server 2014.

Comment: I would guess there is a foreign key reference to a row that is going to be deleted.

Comment: Yes. The thing is that this runs in a night job and in the morning we can't reproduce this error.